# Is it possible to add a Child Of modifier without changing position of the child?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

Currently, when I add a child-of modifier, the child jumps to the parent's head and rotates.

[image]

Why is that?

And more importantly, can I have blender not do that and keep the bone where and how it was, instead?

(I just want to "parent" a second armature to the first as if I had one armature where I parented with `keep offset`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in the constraint, click on the *Set Inverse* button. By default, the child will stick to its parent, but if you click *Set Inverse* it will keep its original position (like a *Parent* > *Keep Offset*).

Comment: A little explanation as to what *Set Inverse* does might be nice here.

Comment: ok it's done   ;)